# how to limit the characters of an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, math

I have this 'lista' array and each object returns a different value. but I have to treat this value.

example: the `lista[1]` returns: `[466.1637615180899, 'A#']` . But I want that it returns just `['466.1638', 'A#']`, so I need to show 8 string characters no numbers.

how can I do that?

```
  const D = [440 * d, 'D']
  const DS = [440 * ds, 'D#']
  const E = [440 * e, 'E']
  const ES = [440 * es, 'E#']
  const F = [440 * f, 'F']
  const FS = [440 * fs, 'F#']

     const lista = [A, AS, B, BS, C, CS, D, DS, E, ES, F, FS]
      
      if(semitons >= 0 && semitons < 13){
        return lista[semitons]
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Map over the array and convert the first element to a string and trim it at 8 characters.

```js
lista.map(l => ([l[0].toString().substring(0,8), l[1]]))
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

```
lista.map(val => ([val[0].toFixed(4), val[1]]))
```

As above but I would use the toFixed method as it is shorter and straightforward.

The toFixed() method converts a number into a string, rounding to a specified number of decimals.